# CodeIgniter Resize Image function is not working

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have some problem in this code. This code is working on my local windows based system. But the same code in not working on online server. I have a function that convert the big images in to small size images according to the parameters. the code of this function is given below.

```
public function do_resize($source_file, $target_folder, $height = 128, $width = 128){

    $filename = $source_file;
    $temp_data = explode('/',$filename);
    $new_filename = end($temp_data);

    $temp_data = explode('.', $new_filename);
    $ext = end($temp_data);
    $new_filename = $temp_data[0] . $width .'-'. $height .'.'. $ext;
    $source_path = $filename;


    $folder_path = '';
    $temp_folder = explode('/',$target_folder);

    foreach ($temp_folder as $folder) {
        $folder_path .=$folder . '/';
        if (!file_exists($folder_path)) {
            mkdir($folder_path);
        }
    }
    $target_path = $target_folder;

    if (file_exists($source_file)) //file_exists of a url returns false.It should be real file path
    {
        return $folder_path . $new_filename;
    }



    if(isset($config_manip)){
        unset($config_manip);
    }

    $config_manip = array(
        'image_library'     => 'gd2',
        'source_image'      => $source_path,
        'maintain_ratio'    => FALSE,
        'new_image'         => $target_path,
        'create_thumb'      => TRUE,
        'thumb_marker'      =>  $width . '-'. $height,
        'width'             => $width,
        'height'            => $height
    );

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->library('image_lib');

    $CI->image_lib->initialize($config_manip);
    if (!$CI->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $CI->image_lib->display_errors();
        echo "<br>";
        echo $config_manip['source_image'];
    }
    // clear //
    $CI->image_lib->clear();
    return $folder_path . $new_filename;
}
```

I am calling this function like this.

```
$name = $this->imageresize->do_resize($brand['logo'], $target_folder, 50, 50);
```

Then input parameter `$brand['logo']` have this value "uploads/images/system/placeholder.png" and parameter `$target_folder` have this value "uploads/images/cache/brands/brand-logo".
I did not get any error from this code. but It is not resizing the images also. I also set the permission of the directory to 777.

Any one have some solution for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if (file_exists($source_file)) //file_exists of a url returns false.It should be real file path
{
    return $folder_path . $new_filename;
}
```

on

```
if (file_exists($folder_path . $new_filename)) //file_exists of a url returns false.It should be real file path
{
    return $folder_path . $new_filename;
}
```

AND $config_manip:

```
'new_image'         => $target_path,
```

ON

```
'new_image'         => $folder_path . $new_filename,
```

:)

Comment: Arkadiusz G: Thanks for your response. I already found the problem. But your reply is correct. Thanks again.